# ibm mobilefirst - call javascript adapter from java adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Anyone knows - How to call javascript adapter from java adapter?

I have created a javascript adapter that will invoke a soap service, then my restful service are Java Adapters. How to invoke a method in javascript adapter from the java Adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `createJavascriptAdapterRequest` on `AdaptersAPI`to call
a JavaScript adapter procedure from a Java adapter

```
HttpUriRequest req = adaptersAPI.createJavascriptAdapterRequest(AdapterName, ProcedureName, [parameters]);
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(req);
JSONObject jsonObj = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(response);
```

Reference:

[Advanced Adapter Usage and Mashup](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/)